# Analyticity of infinitely oscillatory functions

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions

I have a simple question: if $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is analytic, can it be infinitely oscillatory (by which I mean something like $\sin(1/x)$ ?

Comment: It depends on what property of $\sin{(1/x)}$ you mean: an infinite number of turning points? Do the oscillations have to have the same amplitude?

Comment: If it is analytic, then in particular it is continuous at zero.  Do you allow that for your "infinitely oscillatory" functions?

Comment: The zeros of analytic functions are isolated.

Comment: @Chappers Yes I mean an infinite number of turning points, and no the oscillations need not have the same amplitude. And yes I also allow it to be continuous at zero

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla   Thanks for this comment, now that I think of it, I suppose I can prove what you said using the identity theorem? (please correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: @AshutoshSimha, right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if $U=f^{-1} (f(x))$ is the preimage of $f(x)$ then $x$ must be isolated in $U$.

Comment: Do you consider the pre-image of a constant value here? (like the zeros of the function or something?) in that case is your conclusion based on the identity theorem?

Comment: yes, for fixed $x$, $y=f(x)$ the set $f^{-1}(y)$ consists of isolated points only (in the domain where $f$ is analytic). Being analytic at $x$ means that $f$ has a convergent power-series expansion in a ngbh of $x$, whence admit a holomorphic extension (in a complex nghb of $x$). And for a holomorphic function it is well-known that the zero-set (or constant value set) consists of isolated points only.